# VS Code Squiggle line in HTML and CSS files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I updated VS Code to Version: 1.61.2 a week ago and I started noticing few error and warning squiggly lines in my CSS files. I have been working on this project for quite a while now, but these started showing up recently.\

**How does VS Code calculate and display these error/warning lines and how to control these settings?**

Few sample error categories are - `compact-api/html`, `compact-api/css`, `css-prefix-order`:

> - 'meta[name=theme-color]' is not supported by Firefox, Firefox for Android, Internet Explorer, Opera, Safari < 15, Safari on iOS < 15 (`compact-api/html`)
> - 'transition' should be listed after '-moz-transition' (`css-prefix-order`)
> - 'display: grid' is not supported by Internet Explorer. Add 'display: -ms-grid' to support Internet Explorer 10+ (`compact-api/css`)

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM8O5.png):

[image: Screenshot of Problems tab in VS Code terminal]

Answer (score 1):

Its https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/visual-studio-code/webhint

```
{
  "vscode-edge-devtools.webhint": false
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Nermo. Do you happen to know if this is a new feature? It doesn't look very old when I google it. But I noticed these started up recently in my project.

Comment: I also found this article which talks about [webhint in VS Code](https://dev.to/hxlnt/these-vs-code-extensions-help-you-fix-accessibility-and-compatibility-bugs-while-you-code-2196) and related extension. This article is published 6 months back, so I think this is relatively a new feature in VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled Microsoft Edge Tools for VS Code, and the warnings went away.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the linting function but not see those Internet Explorer-related errors they can be removed by creating a `hintrc` file with an entry like:

```
{
  "extends": ["development"],
  "browserslist": ["defaults", "not IE 11"]
}
```

so that it is no longer checking for compatibility with IE11, for example.

See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70676598/836330