# How to disable "'flex' is not supported by Internet Explorer < 11. Add '-ms-flex' to support Internet Explorer 10+." in VS code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

My react project has a couple of "flex" compatibility errors. How to remove these errors in VS code? I already used postcss in my project.

[image]

```
'flex' is not supported by Internet Explorer < 11. Add '-ms-flex' to support Internet Explorer 10+.
'flex-direction' is not supported by Internet Explorer < 11. Add '-ms-flex-direction' to support Internet Explorer 10+.
'transform' is not supported by Internet Explorer < 10. Add '-ms-transform' to support Internet Explorer 9+.
```

Comment: I think it says right in the error message how to fix it. Is there some other type of fix you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Collind,  I used postcss in my project, I mean how to avoid these warningns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Microsoft Edge Tools extension uses the webHint extension - which is apparently generating those error messages.

As suggested in [installing edge generates warning messages from Webhints and offers no obvious recourse other than uninstalling it all](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-edge-devtools/issues/596) you can try these methods to disable those warnings

1. disable the setting `Vscode-edge-devtools: Webhint` but that will disable all error messages, not just those about IE11; or

---

After creating a `hintrc` file (https://webhint.io/docs/user-guide/configuring-webhint/summary/#create-a-hintrc-file):

You could turn off all CSS compat warnings with this .hintrc (pretty heavy-handed still):

```
{
    "extends": ["development"],
    "hints": {
        "compat-api/css": "off"
    }
}
```

Or you could adjust your target browsers to exclude browsers you don't care about (maybe Internet Explorer?) with this `.hintrc`:

```
{
    "extends": ["development"],
    "browserslist": ["defaults", "not IE 11"]
}
```

Or you could ignore just the `backdrop-filter` CSS property and still get feedback for others with this `.hintrc`:

```
{
    "extends": ["development"],
    "hints": {
        "compat-api/css": ["default", {
            "ignore": ["backdrop-filter"]
        }]
    }
}
```

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-edge-devtools/issues/596#issuecomment-961496154

---

Or you should be able to disable those error messages by setting an environment variable, see [Setting properties using environment variables](https://webhint.io/docs/user-guide/configuring-webhint/summary/#setting-properties-using-environment-variables)

Possibly this environment variable, but I haven't tried it:

`"webhint_browserlist_" = ["defaults", "not IE 11"]`

Comment: webhint honours browserslist set in either .browserlistrc or in your package.json file: 
https://webhint.io/docs/user-guide/configuring-webhint/browser-context/#page-heading

Answer (score -2):

You can just uninstall the Microsoft edge tools and restart the editor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a great comment, but not enough information to warrant answering. Consider editing your answer